# Organising subscriptions of dependent observables

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

Trying to fully wrap my head around FRP (using rxjs) and struggling a bit with organizing dependent streams and managing their outputs.

I have 3 streams: `user$`, `userTeams$` and `currentTeam$` and can describe them as

- `userTeams$ = f(user$, userTeamsChanges$)`
- `currentTeam$ = f(userTeams$, currentTeamSelection$)`

This makes the data flow easy, but now I need to subscribe to them and create some output.

My instinct would be to combine them back into one stream and manage my output in the subscription:

```
const dataChangedEvents$ = combineLatest([
  user$,
  userTeams$,
  currentTeam$
]).subscribe(change => emitEvent(change))
```

But I feel like now I subscribed to `user$` 3 times, since `userTeams$` and `currentTeam$` are both derived from `user$`.

The alternative is to only do `currentTeam$.subscribe()` and have each stream emit its own events via `tap`. But this makes it so it's really unclear which streams I am actually subscribed to and which ones are just sitting idly, esp. as the app grows.

Is there a solution that gives me the best of both worlds?

- makes dependencies between streams clear
- subscribes to each stream only once
- performs well

Comment: Check shareReplay

Comment: Check also withLatestFrom: `currentTeam$.pipe(withLatestFrom(...))`